# What series was Tomoko talking about?

Tags: watamote

When talking about anime with Yuu-chan at "SterTully's" coffee shop, Tomoko says:

> There's a lot of moeshit anime this season.
>   Slice-of-life anime is all they air these days, because of the new content restrictions.
>   There are some pretty interesting series, though! Like that EFB show...

<sup>This is what the subs from the version I saw said, the actual content may be slightly different.</sup>

[image: Tomoko and Yuu talking about anime.]

Is Tomoko talking about any series that is actually coming out this season? Or is it just made-up (much like EFB seems to be)?

Comment: According to TV Tropes, "EFB" is referring to "AKB0048".

Comment: @JonLin Ah, I thought EFB was the producer or the network broadcasting the series.

Comment: I believe this has something to do with the "Eternal Force Blizzard" 2ch meme... basically it's a technique/magic which instantly kills your opponent... it's probably being used in the context of of a placeholder for some "awesome sounding" thing. E.g. Did you see that ZNPR (Zombie Ninja Pirate Robot) movie?

Comment: @JonLin I can't find any reference connecting EFB to AKB0048, can you cite the particular page that reference this?

Comment: @Krazer On the [Wakamote page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/NoMatterHowILookAtItItsYouGuysFaultImNotPopular) the "EFB" link goes to "AKB0048", though the AKB page doesn't mention EFB.

Comment: I can't say that's canonical reference that can be used to back up this claim. In the post by the OP, it's noted that Tomoko said "There are some pretty interesting series, though! Like that EFB show..." which indicates it not to be a moeshit show, but an interesting one. I think that this contradicts the TV Trope entry linking to AKB0048.

Comment: I have no idea where they got that from, there's no explanation anywhere, but that entry was edited a bunch of times and the link itself was never changed.

Comment: Doesn't Tomoko always use the actual names of things, but they are censored? Couldn't EFB actually correlate to something that exists? I don't remember her using any parody names.

Answer (score 8):

The first couple of chapters from the Watamote manga were published at the end of 2011. This scene hasn't changed from the anime, so the possible 'moeshit' that she's referring to could be something like

- [The K-On!! Movie](http://www.tbs.co.jp/anime/k-on/)
- [Tantei Opera Milky Holmes Season 2](http://milky-holmes.com/)
- [Mourestsu Pirates](http://www.starchild.co.jp/special/mo-retsu/)
- [More found here.](http://www.moetron.com/2011/10/02/winter-2011-12-visual-guide-and-anime-listing/)

But I think it's more of a commentary on how moe-styled anime has become popular recently, and not about any shows in particular

As mentioned by @Jon Lin earlier, [AKB0048](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/19/AKB0048_anime_poster.jpeg) could be what EFB is referring to. Note AKB0048 started airing in April of 2012. The characters are argueably moe also.

[image]

Comment: I don't think "EFB" is a cover term for any of the series you mention (or even anything related to moe) on TV Tropes or elsewhere. Also Tomoko doesn't refer to EFB as a moeshit show and mentions it to be pretty interesting, so it definitely can't be a parody name for a moe show.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a reference to [ef: A Tale of Memories](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2924/ef:_A_Tale_of_Memories.), made earlier by the same director. 
This show is also referenced on [Episode 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGhPq.png) and the OVA.